# Ajax API call inside a while loop inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

So I'm making an API mashup for a class. Right now, I'm getting a json response from Google Maps API. I'm getting 5 waypoints from the response by using a for loop. The problem I'm trying to fix is some of the coords are in dead space and have no pictures associated with them. I'd like to make an ajax call at each of the 4 iterations, but if one doesnt have a picture, then it would iterate till it found one, then go back to where it left off.
I tried using a while loop so that it would make the call, and upon a succesful coordinate the while loop variable would get set to true, and then it would break out of the while loop and then go back to the for loop which would iterate to the next "waypoint". As of now I'm not getting errors, the site is timing out, maybe too many calls? Maybe I'm doing something recursively?

```
// so this for loop divides the hundreds of steps by 1/4 of the total length.
for (i=0; i<polyPoints.length; i+=quarters) {
    // gets the coords for the current iteration.
    var lat = polyPoints[i][0];
    var lng = polyPoints[i][1];

    var hasPic = false;
    var origI = i;

    //while loop runs through and checks to see if the coordinate has pictures at it.
    while (hasPic == false){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            ajaxI: i,
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng+'&distance=5000&access_token='+token,
            success: function(data){
                i = this.ajaxI;
                //if null,increases the iteration by one, and then runs through the loop again, checking the next coordinate? I hope.
                if(typeof data.data[0] === "undefined" || data.meta.code == 400){
                    i++;
                    console.log("i increased to "+i);
                }else{
                    //if the pic is there then it assigns a random picture from the result to the images array.
                    images.push(data.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.data.length)].images.low_resolution.url);

                    //sets while loop to stop
                    hasPic = true;

                    //loads the current iterations coordinates for the later for loop to create markers.
                    waypoints.push([lat,lng]);
                }
            }, //data.data[0].images.low_resolution.url
            error: function(data){
                i = this.ajaxI;
                i++;
                //images.push(img/test.jpg");
            }
        }).responseText;
    }//waypoints.push([lat,lng]);

    //resets the i back to the original iteration before it got increased
    i = origI;
}
```

Comment: Your code currently sits in an infinite loop spitting out ajax requests

Comment: Maybe i've missed something, but where do you update your lat & lng variables in your while loop? The while loop seems to check the same coordinations again and again, if no pic was found. And that fails into an infinite loop, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, using `$.Deferred`:

```
function tryGetImage(firstI, maxI) {
    var dfr = $.Deferred();
    var inner = function(i) {
        if(i >= maxI) dfr.reject();

        var lat = polyPoints[i][0];
        var lng = polyPoints[i][1];
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "jsonp",
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng+'&distance=5000&access_token='+token,
        }).done(function(data){
            //if null,increases the iteration by one, and then runs through the loop again, checking the next coordinate? I hope.
            if(typeof data.data[0] === "undefined" || data.meta.code == 400){
                inner(i + 1);
            }else{
                var img = data.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.data.length)].images.low_resolution.url);
                dfr.resolve(img, [lat, lng]);
            }
        ).fail(function(data){
            inner(i + 1);
        });
    };
    inner(firstI);
    return dfr.promise();
}

var dfrs = [];
for (i=0; i<polyPoints.length; i+=quarters) {
    var dfr = tryGetImages(i, i + quarters)
    dfr.done(function(img, coords) {
        images.push(img);
        waypoints.push(coords);
    })
    dfrs.push(dfr);
}
$.when.apply($, dfrs).always(function() {
    console.log("All requests complete");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Triple equal (===) on line 14?
I think you meant == ?

Comment: No, `===` is valid (and generally preferred, even).